# ruby injections in coffeescript execute despite conditions

Tags: ruby, coffeescript

In RoR project -> views -> ... -> create.js.coffee 
code

```
$("<%= j(render partial: 'invoice_equipment/invoice_equipment', object: @invoice_equipment) %>").appendTo("#invoice_equipment_list")
```

executes always, not dependent of conditions before.

In this file I want show some message for user, if he try create record, that already exists in DB.

If remove that line from file, another js working correctly line by line.

All file:

```
if "<% @invoice_equipment %>"
  $("<%= j(render partial: 'invoice_equipment/invoice_equipment', object: @invoice_equipment) %>").appendTo("#invoice_equipment_list")
  M.toast({html: "<%= I18n.t('invoice_equipment.added') %>", displayLength: 3000, classes: 'rounded'})
else
  M.toast({html: "<%= I18n.t('invoice_equipment.already_added') %>", displayLength: 3000, classes: 'rounded'})

$('#new_invoice_equipment')[0].reset()
$('#invoice_equipment_equipment').focus()
```

@invoice_equipment can be nil or ActiveRecord. But in both times RoR try render partial and fall if @invoice_equipment is nil.

So, I think, injected ruby code executed before creating js file.

I'm right?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely because you're using a mix of javascript and rails templating in your conditional. Try reformatting your conditional so it's not using the javascript `if`:

```
<% if @invoice_equipment.present? %>
  # Your code to render when the object is present
<% else %>
  # Your code to render when the object is missing
<% end %>
```

Comment: Tnx for your reply, but this not works. CoffeeScript can't compile to js and rails show error: 
`ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: [stdin]:3:1: missing indentation)`